# How is this list is integrated in Dropdownbutton items using map?Can anyone explain?

Tags: flutter, dropdown

This is defined in Class state :

`static var _priorities = ["High", "Low"];`**strong text**

This is inside the build widget:

`ListTile(
              title: DropdownButton(
                  items: _priorities.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: dropDownStringItem,
                      child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: null),
            )`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dart documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/map.html) on `List.map`:

> Returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by calling f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order.

That is, `map` returns a `Iterable` that contains every element from the original `List` transformed. The way the items in the list are transformed depends on the closure you pass to the `map` method. In your case:

1. You take every `String` from the `_priorities` list: "High" and "Low".
2. You build a `DropDownMenuItem<String>` for every one of them, by passing a `DropDownMenuItem Function(String)` to the `map` method. The closure you are passing to `map` is a function that takes a `String` and returns a `DropDownMenuItem`
3. Then, you call `toList()` to transform the `Iterable` returned by `map` to a `List`.

That way, you have transformed your `List<String>` in a `List<DropDownMenuItem>` by taking every `String` in the original list and building a `DropDownMenuItem` for every string.